# Excel iOS app: Keyboard shortcut for Edit cell

Tags: ios, keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

I am used to using <kbd>F2</kbd> as the keyboard shortcut to edit a cell in Microsoft Excel for desktop.

The Excel iOS seems not to have this shortcut (see [Use an external keyboard with Excel for iPad](https://support.office.com/article/use-an-external-keyboard-with-excel-for-ipad-e484e2b0-7a92-4c6b-ad83-ad16e3ee71e8)).

What is the corresponding keyboard shortcut for Excel for iOS?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Unlike a forum, Ask Different is a question & answer website. It would fit the format of the website if you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/361448/edit) your post to formulate it as a question and share the answer in the answer section below. The information will certainly be helpful for others looking for similar issue. Your question and answer may also get upvoted by the folks who will find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

After trying systematically I found out that on my Apple Smart Keyboard Folio <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> does the trick.